# What is this stalemate on Covid relief payments all about?

Tags: united-states, congress, covid-19, house-of-representatives

Trump said he wants to raise the size of payments to $2,000, the Democrats are all for it, but the Republicans still block it. What is the disagreement? There was also something with foreign aid that the Republicans, including Trump, oppose but the Democrats support. First, what does it have to do with the Covid relief package (why can't it be voted on with a separate bill?).

Secondly, what foreign aid are they talking about, why is it controversial? Lastly, why is Trump suddenly backing generous across-the-board handouts if it's traditionally something the Democrats propose (especially left-leaning) and, conversely, something the Republicans usually dismiss as "socialism"?

Edit: [This](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61109/whats-with-the-trump-veto-due-to-insufficient-individual-covid-relief?noredirect=1&lq=1) post answers only one of the several questions I asked. It should be reopened.

Comment: Can't really be answered without being able to read Trump's mind. At a guess, he's trying to buy public support for his attempt to stay in office after January 20th.  You might compare with the way Julius Caesar gave handouts to the Roman plebs to buy popularity.

Comment: Not sure this q is distinct from https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61109/whats-with-the-trump-veto-due-to-insufficient-individual-covid-relief (I'm not using my close vote because it would be unilateral given the gold-US thingy I have.)

Comment: See also https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50052/are-foreign-governments-receiving-4-7-billion-as-a-result-of-the-u-s-covid-sti